# Composition of EEX energy prices

Tags: energy-economics

I am working currently on EEX energy price data from Germany and so far I couldn't find out, if the prices already include taxes and the German Renewable Energy Act feed-in tarif (EEG-Umlage).

I would appreciate help.

Answer (score 2):

They don't include anything. It is the pure price for 1 MWh.

Edit.

The producers have been paid the tariffs, which lowers their short run marginal costs quite a lot. There has not been added any taxes to the consumers at this point, however.